# how to internal storage item display on another activity of editbox

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, internal

I am a new android developer. my problem is how items display from internal storage to another activity of the edit box. internal storage file contains (name, age, position) that file item display on three edit box of another activity.

In my project user select MSG from Inbox and that MSG display on text view of activity_main.xml .when I click save button that file stored in internal storage but when I click on the read button that all item display on one edit box not separately all three edit box from internal storage .

for example in my internal storage file contain(abc,14,ANDROID DEVLOPER) that all item display of another activity of three edit box separately.
    **Mainctivity.java**

```
Read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //private Context context;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageBox.class);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context,MessageBox.class);
                 try{
                     FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
                     int c;
                     String temp="";
                     while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                        temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),data.class);

                        //String msg = null;
                        in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", temp); 
                     startActivity(in);

                    // et.setText(temp);
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file read",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }


                  }catch(Exception e){

                  }
        }
    });}

     public void save(View view){
          data = tv.getText().toString();
          try {
             FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
             fOut.write(data.getBytes());
             fOut.close();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
**data.java**
setContentView(R.layout.data);
        et11 = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.eText123));
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Msg_Detail");
        //String msg = intent.getExtras().getString("Msg_Detail");
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.eText123)).setText(msg);
        //et11.setText(msg);   

activity_main.xml contain save, read and text view and data.xml contain three edit box(name,age,position).how that msg display on edit box of data.xml from internal storage.
Internal file generate and user select msg display on text view of activity_main.xml of another project but how internal file item display on edit box.
                problem is when I click read button all data item display on one edit box.
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet...

```
 while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                    temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),data.class);

                    //String msg = null;
                    in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", temp); 
                 startActivity(in);

                // et.setText(temp);
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file read",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
```

is actually doing nothing else but starting a new activity and pausing the current activity as soon as the file stream reads the first byte and it also leaves the file stream open. That's why you are probably getting nothing in `data.java`.

You should wait till the file stream finishes reading the file to start the new activity and make sure you close that stream. So, move the code that creates the intent, starts the activity and shows the toast out of the while loop...

```
FileInputStream in = null;
int c;
String temp="";

try{
    fin = openFileInput(file);

    while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
        temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){...}
finally{
    if(in != null)
        in.close();
}

Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),data.class);
in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", temp); 

startActivity(in);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
```

Comment: This answer should work for you. Since the file stores data in the format (abc,14,ANDROID DEVLOPER), what you can do is that once you get this exact format data in another activity, just parse/split this data string on comma ',' and then assign these strings in their respective edit box.

Comment: click on read button item directly separated and display on edit box of data.java

Comment: @user3920751 what's that half-sentence supposed mean?